# Bootstrap: How to make glyphicons appear only in navbar collapse?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, glyphicons

Like I mentioned in the title of the question, I want the glyphicons for my list items in the navbar to appear only in mobile devices i.e. when navbar is collapsed. I don't want them to be visible in the md, lg.. devices with those list items. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3.x has [helper classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) for this task. So, wrap your Glyphicon elements in a span with the relevant classes, and they will only be visible in the extra-small media range:

```
<span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
</span>
```